# Show that these equations can come from two others (differential equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, substitution, derived-functors

so I have a scenario whereby a disease is modeled using SEIS (Susceptible, Exposed, Infected, Susceptible) where:

- Susceptible (S) individuals become exposed (E) at a rate $A$ individuals per day
- Exposed (E) individuals become infected (I) at a rate $B$ individuals per day
- Infected (I) individuals do not gain immunity and become susceptible again at a rate $C$ per day.
- $s$, $e$ and $i$ are the frequencies of S, E and I of the total population, $N$.
- $R_0$ is $A$/$C$
- $s$ + $e$ + $i$ = 1

I have derived a series of differential equations for this model:
$$ds/dt = -As + Ci$$
$$de/dt = -Be + As$$
$$di/dt = -Ci + Be$$

I am now required to show that:

$$ds/dt = -A(1-s-e)(s-1/R_0)$$
$$de/dt = As(1-s-e)-Be$$

I assume I need to use the fact that $s$ + $e$ + $i$ = 1 to do so but I've tried but am stuck. How do I go about getting these two 'new' equations?

Comment: The two equations for $de/dt$ are clearly different (if $As\neq As(1-s-e)$), which looks like a mistake. But it sounds like this is just using $i=1-s-e$ to eliminate $i$.

Comment: @Dap that must mean my differential equations are wrong...but these seem to be okay. Am I missing something with them?

Comment: It looks like in the correct equations, susceptible individuals become exposed at a rate of $Asi$ instead of $As$. (Anyway, your $As$ doesn't match the description of $A$ individuals per day.)

Comment: I fixed a mistake with my ODEs. They were missing an i. (i.e. Asi).

Comment: So the question is no longer relevant? You could delete the question or answer it yourself, so people don't think it's still an open question